# Return value of an array for each item in a list

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm still quite new to writing functions and PHP so please excuse me if this is easy. Let me provide a little background...

I have built an e-commerce site using MarketPress by WPMUDev and trying to write a function that will show the stock remaining depending on the product variation selected.

In MarketPress, if you have more than one variation of a product, e.g. Shirt (Blue/Black/White) then you specify the one product with three variations. On the single product page, you have a drop down box for each variant.

The code I have so far will find the stock level of the initial product only and not the variants. Please see below:

```
    function mp_product_stock_sc( $atts ){
    global $post;
    $product_id = $post->ID;
    $stock = get_post_meta($product_id, 'mp_inventory', true);
    $high_st = 1;
    //return 'Default Stock: ' . $stock[0];

    if ($stock[0] <= $high_st AND $stock[0] > 0 ) {
        //return 'Hurry! We only have ' . $stock[0] . ' in stock!';
        return 'Hurry! Only one left in stock!';
    } elseif ($stock[0] == 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return 'In Stock';
    }


    return 'Stock: ' . $stock[0];
}

    add_shortcode( 'mp_product_stock', 'mp_product_stock_sc' );
```

I know that the function is selecting the first variant in $stock[0] because the [0] is explicitly defined. By manually writing [1] it would select the next variant and so on.

What I need to do is, on the product variation drop down list, for each variant to have next to it the stock, e.g:

Shirt (Blue) - In Stock 
Shirt (Black) - Hurry only 1 left! 
Shirt (White) - In Stock

I know where to put the code, just not how to return the value.

Any advice greatly appreciated. There's probably a much better way of writing this too...

Thanks!

Edit: Adding below the code where the drop down is generated.

```
//create select list if more than one variation

                    if (is_array($meta["mp_price"]) && count($meta["mp_price"]) > 1 && empty($meta["mp_file"])) {

                            $variation_select = '<select class="mp_product_variations" name="variation">';

                            foreach ($meta["mp_price"] as $key => $value) {

                                    $disabled = (in_array($key, $no_inventory)) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';

                                    $variation_select .= '<option value="' . $key . '"' . $disabled . '>' . esc_html($meta["mp_var_name"][$key]) . ' - ';

                                    if ($meta["mp_is_sale"] && $meta["mp_sale_price"][$key]) {

                                            $variation_select .= $mp->format_currency('', $meta["mp_sale_price"][$key]);

                                    } else {

                                            $variation_select .= $mp->format_currency('', $value);

                                    }

                                    $variation_select .= "</option>\n";

                            }

                            $variation_select .= "</select>&nbsp;\n";

                    } else {

                            $button .= '<input type="hidden" name="variation" value="0" />';

                    }
```

Comment: "Return value of an array for each item in a list" - sounds like a task for something like `map` in functional languages, don't know whether PHP has one.

Comment: Do you have access to the scripting for the drop-down list or where does this script run in relation to the generation of the drop-down?

Comment: @Rasclatt Thanks for the response. I have added the code where the drop down is generated.

Comment: If I was to do something like this, I would make sure I have a query that has the product info, and if the availability is in a different place/array I would make sure that both have matching keys. So like `$item['product']['123'] = 'Shirt (Blue)';` and my other array would be like `$status['product']['123'] = 'Unavailable';`. If you have two comparative arrays or able to make two, you can do it that way. The other way is to have your function require the item code the function returns the status.

Comment: In the `$meta` array, do you have the item code available like `$meta['mp_itemcode']` (I don't know what the key would be called, so this is a for-instance...) or is `$key` the item code in your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the fact that you have an item code that you can feed into the method:

**EDIT:** I added a `Randomizer` method that will do two things. 1) You can set it to return a random number to check that the `$calltoaction` if statement is working (set the second variable in `Randomizer` to `true` instead of `false`) and 2) It will check that your number is numeric and return it back if it is. If not numeric, it will return 'err' which means it's not a number.

```
class StockCheck
        {
            public  static  function Fetch($itemcode, $high_st = 1)
                {
                    // Check your stock on this item code (I pressume this is what it's doing.
                    // If not, this is what it should to do.)
                    $stock      =   get_post_meta($itemcode, 'mp_inventory', true);
                    // Assign number. If randomizer set to true, it will just generate a random num
                    // to test the if statement below. Change to false to return true number
                    $_inStock   =   self::Randomizer($stock[0],false);

                    if($_inStock !== 'err') {
                            if($_inStock !== 0) {
                                    // If stock is less than or equal to 10
                                    if($_inStock <= 10)
                                        $calltoaction   =   'Hurry! Only '.$_inStock.' Left in Stock!';
                                    // If stock is greater than 10 but less than or equal to 20
                                    elseif($_inStock > 10 && $_inStock <= 20)
                                        $calltoaction   =   'Only a Few Left. Going fast!';
                                    // Anthing else is just in stock
                                    else
                                        $calltoaction   =   'In Stock';
                                }
                            // If zero, out of stock.
                            else
                                $calltoaction   =   'Out of Stock, Sorry!';
                        }

                    return (isset($calltoaction))? $calltoaction:'Error: Stock value not numeric';
                }

            protected static function Randomizer($value = 0, $randomizer = false)
                {
                    // If set to true, it will just generate a random number for testing purposes
                    $defVal =   ($randomizer == true)? rand(0,30):$value;
                    // If $defVal is not a numeric, return "err"
                    return (is_numeric($defVal) || $defVal == 0)? $defVal:'err'; 
                }

        }

    if(is_array($meta["mp_price"]) && count($meta["mp_price"]) > 1 && empty($meta["mp_file"])) {
            $variation_select = '<select class="mp_product_variations" name="variation">';
            foreach ($meta["mp_price"] as $key => $value) {
                    $disabled           =   (in_array($key, $no_inventory)) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
                    $variation_select   .=  '<option value="' . $key . '"' . $disabled . '>' . esc_html($meta["mp_var_name"][$key]) . ' - ';
                    $variation_select   .=  ($meta["mp_is_sale"] && $meta["mp_sale_price"][$key])? $mp->format_currency('', $meta["mp_sale_price"][$key]): $mp->format_currency('', $value);
                    // This is where you would feed your item code...
                    $variation_select   .=  StockCheck::Fetch($meta["mp_itemcode"],1);
                    $variation_select   .=  "</option>\n";
                }
            $variation_select .= "</select>&nbsp;\n";
        }
    else 
        $button .= '<input type="hidden" name="variation" value="0" />';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I have implemented this and seems like we're getting somewhere. Each variation of a product in a drop down box now has "In Stock" next to it. The trouble is, all products say "In Stock". When stock levels for each variation reach "1", I would like it to say "Only 1 left in stock". How would I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: You have been very helpful so far so please bear with me. How would I switch the `if` statement? I need each variation to echo "In Stock", "Out of Stock" etc. At the moment all products say "In Stock". (Once this is fixed, I'm going to have a long hard play on Code Academy.

Comment: No worries. I really appreciate the help you've provided.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's still only returning the first item in stock. I will have a play around with the code and will update with my findings. Thanks

Comment: If you repost your current code it can probably be solved in a few minutes. One thing to check is that `$stock[0]` is a numeric, so I would echo it on the page to see what it is saying. It may not be what you expected. For instance is it possible it's not `$stock[0]` but rather something like `$stock[0]['in_stock']` or something like that?

Comment: See my revised code above it will help you troubleshoot the in stock messaging.